# Error using Spring Integration with Spring batch admin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Trying to tie those two together. But that exception occurs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
```

My gradle script:

```
ext {
    springIntegrationVersion = '4.0.3.RELEASE'
    springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.0.0.M2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    //SI
     compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion")

     //kafka
     compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:$springIntegrationKafkaVersion") {
         exclude module: 'log4j'
         exclude module: 'jms'
         exclude module: 'jmxtools'
         exclude module: 'jmxri'
     }
```

..

This is gradle depencies tree:

```
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2
|    |    |         +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.15
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.0.15
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.15
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.0.15
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.15
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.3.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.2.RELEASE
|         +--- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:1.0
|         |    \--- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:1.0
|         +--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7
|         |    +--- xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1
|         |    \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|         +--- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.2
|         +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:3.0.2.RELEASE
|         |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.0.RELEASE
|         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.1
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.2.7.RELEASE -> 3.0.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.2.7.RELEASE -> 3.0.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.0.2.RELEASE -> 1.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
|    |    \--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    +--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2 -> 2.4
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.15
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-resources:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    +--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
+--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:1.0.0.M2
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:1.7.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.3
|    |    |    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.5
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.4.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.tukaani:xz:1.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7
|    |    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    |    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6 (*)
|    +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-annotation:2.2.0
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:2.2.0
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 -> 1.7.7
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.1.1
|         +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:2.2.0 (*)
|         +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.5
|         +--- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.3.4
|         |    \--- jline:jline:0.9.94
|         |         \--- junit:junit:3.8.1 -> 4.12
|         |              \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|         +--- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:3.2
|         +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1
|         \--- com.101tec:zkclient:0.3
|              \--- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.3.1 -> 3.3.4 (*)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
     +--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8
     |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
     |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.3.RELEASE
          \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

I almost sure the spring-batch-admin does the problem. having spring-batch and Spring-integration alone worked perfect.

Any idea how to nail this one? is that really coming from  spring-batch-admin ?

thank you.

As suggested I downgraded into Spring 3.x to run this project
I am still having the same errors.

New gradle script:
...

```
ext {
    springIntegrationVersion = '3.0.6.RELEASE'
    springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.0.0.M2'
}

dependencies {
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    //SI
     compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion")

     //kafka
     compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:$springIntegrationKafkaVersion") {
         exclude module: 'log4j'
         exclude module: 'jms'
         exclude module: 'jmxtools'
         exclude module: 'jmxri'
     }
```

Dependencies tree:

```
testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java: -> 5.1.34
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2
|    |    |         +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.15
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.0.15
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.15
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.0.15
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.15
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.3.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.3.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.2.RELEASE
|         +--- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:1.0
|         |    \--- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:1.0
|         +--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7
|         |    +--- xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1
|         |    \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|         +--- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.2
|         +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:3.0.2.RELEASE
|         |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.0.RELEASE
|         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1
|    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.1
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.2.7.RELEASE -> 3.0.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.2.7.RELEASE -> 3.0.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.0.2.RELEASE -> 1.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
|    |    \--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    +--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2 -> 2.4
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.15
|    +--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-resources:1.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    +--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
+--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:1.0.0.M2
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:1.7.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.3
|    |    |    +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.5
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.4.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.tukaani:xz:1.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7
|    |    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    |    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.7
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6 (*)
|    +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-annotation:2.2.0
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.0.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:2.2.0
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 -> 1.7.7
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.1.1
|         +--- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:2.2.0 (*)
|         +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.5
|         +--- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.3.4
|         |    \--- jline:jline:0.9.94
|         |         \--- junit:junit:3.8.1 -> 4.12
|         |              \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|         +--- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:3.2
|         +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1
|         \--- com.101tec:zkclient:0.3
|              \--- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.3.1 -> 3.3.4 (*)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test: -> 1.2.0.RELEASE
     +--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8
     |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
     |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.3.RELEASE
          \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE (*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch Admin is currently in development for our 2.0 release. As part of that release, we will be upgrading the dependencies across the board (including this issue).  If you're willing to work off the latest and greatest, the current master has these changes already applied.  Otherwise, I'll be releasing  Spring Batch Admin 2.0.0.M1 in the coming days.

You can follow the progress of Spring Batch Admin in Jira here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM/

Comment: does the new master using the new spring-integration API which will prevent the following error?

Comment: Yes.  Current master depends on Spring 4 and Spring Integration 4.

Comment: Ive edited my question. For now downgrading into Spring-Integration 3.x but still got the same error? any idea what am I missing? thanks.

Comment: Apparently Spring-Integration with kafka also need spring-integration 4.x. From which repo I can download the new spring-batch-admin master?

Comment: @MichaelMinella : does this mean that Spring Admin Batch 1.3.x wouldn't work with Spring Core 4.x?

Comment: The answer is Yes but only up to Spring Core 4.0.9, as from 4.1.0, MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter was completely removed and hence using Spring Admin Batch 1.3.x with version of Spring core higher or equal to 4.1.0 will cause and exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the issue is with spring-batch-admin. It has a dependency on Spring Integration 3.x which is being resolved to 4.0.3. There were significant changes made between the 3.x and 4.x version of Spring Integration. Mainly, several classes and interfaces were moved out of the Spring Integration project to the core Spring Framework project under the `org.springframework.messaging` package. Either spring-batch-admin needs to be refactored to support Spring Integration 4.x or you'll need to downgrade to Spring Integration 3.x.

Comment: Hi Mark, I downgraded Spring Integration into version 3.x as you suggested but I still get the same error. Please check my edited question