# Spring-batch with spring-integration-kafka

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to integrate spring-batch-admin with spring-integration-kafka to run the consumers. I got the below exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27744507/2725210). Kafka integration will be supported in spring-batch-2.0.0 release.

As of now, what would be the better way to listen kafka consumer in spring?

Comment: You are missing a spring-integration dependency.

Comment: I have spring-integration-core and spring-integration-kafka dependencies in my pom.xml

Comment: Make sure that the versions match and are compatible...

Comment: @M.Deinum I have rechecked jar versions, everything seems correct. But according to the post i linked in the question, these dependencies will be added in spring-batch-admin 2.0 release. Is there a better way to listen for kafka consumers in spring without the batch?

Comment: Why do you need the batch part for listening? That should (or is) part of Spring Integration... What is it you want with the Spring Batch Admin stuff? Also in that question is stated that you would have to use the 2.0.0.M1 earlier versions won't work due to version mismatches in the frameworks.